# Admin: get data from sales_flat_order_address

Tags: admin, sales-order

How can I get a field from sales_flat_order_address and use it in sales admin view?
I've got a boolean field and i like to add a code if it is true

```
<?php if ($myattribyte = 1): ?>
   <p> Some text</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can get the order address data by below code**

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
$billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
$shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
```

You can you get that data from this address object

```
print_r($shippingAddress->getData());
```

You can check your attribute if that contain in address object like

```
if($shippingAddress->getYourAttribute())
{
   // do your stuff here...
}
```

**Same thing you can do for billing address..**